# Write hexadecimal values to binary file with bash

Tags: bash, binary

How can I write an specific number of zeros in a binary file automatically?

I write:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {0..127};
do
    echo -e -n "\x00" >> file.bin
done
```

But looking the file with Bless outputs: `2D 65 20 2D 6E 20 5C 78 30 30 0A` which corresponds to `-e -n \x00`.

Comment: Bash's builtin `echo` should process `-e` and `-n`, but just in case you're running that script with `sh myscript.sh`, take into account that `sh` might be a different shell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`printf` should be portable](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html) and supports octal character escapes:

```
i=0
while [ "$i" -le 127 ]; do
    printf '\000'
    i=$((i+1)) 
done >> file.bin
```

(`printf` isn't required to support hex escapes like `\x00`, but a number of shells support that.)

See [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/170373) for the troubles with `echo`.

Comment: @Wildcard Yes, it will. Which is precisely what the question requested.

Comment: Does this work for values other than nulls?

Answer (score 5):

If it's zeros to a file, then the obvious one is:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=file.bin bs=1 count=128
```

Note that this is pretty inefficient as it goes, as it does single byte writes. You could just as easily use:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=file.bin bs=128 count=1
```

Here, `bs' is the 'block size' and`count` is how many blocks. Better to write one block than lots of little ones!

Note that the above commands do *not* append to `file.bin`, they overwrite it. One way round that is:

```
dd if=/dev/zero bs=128 count=1 >> file.bin
```

Explanation: in the absence of `of=`, `dd` writes to standard output, which is then appended to the output file.

Comment: or just `head -c123 /dev/zero >> file.bin` for arbitrary values of 123. (no need to think explicitly about the block size)

Comment: Mind that `dd if=/dev/zero bs=128 count=1 >> file.bin' does append without cat or a new sub-shell (the pipe `|`).

Answer (score 1):

1. `printf` will re-use the same format for all arguments.
2. The format `%.0s` will print no part of its argument.

Combining these leads to the rather nice

```
$ printf '\0%.0s' {1..128} >128nulls
```

for 128 nulls.